# How to access an image from within a JAR

Tags: java, resources, jar

I know this question (or similar ones) has been asked before, but I still don't understand it.  I've created a jar that has the following internal structure:

JAR file

-configuration

---codeBehind

---commandLine

---gui

---resources

Within the resources folder, I have an image that I'd like to use as an icon, but I can't figure out how to get it. I've tried

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("settings.png"));
setIconImage(icon.getImage());
```

but it throws a `NullPointerException` when I tried to access the image of the icon. I tried to separate the pieces of the command, and `getResources("mypic.png")` returned null.

Any ideas on how I can get it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

From [the documentation of Class](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)):

> Before delegation, an absolute resource name is constructed from the given resource name using this algorithm:
>
> - If the name begins with a '/' ('\u002f'), then the absolute name of the resource is the portion of the name following the '/'.
> - Otherwise, the absolute name is of the following form:
>     modified_package_name/name
>
> Where the modified_package_name is the package name of this object with '/' substituted for '.' ('\u002e').

So you probably want

```
getResource("/settings.png")
```

or

```
getResource("/resources/settings.png")
```

or something similar, depending on your classpath, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

getClass().getResource() will look for a resource with the specified name starting from (relative to) the package the class on which you call getClass() is called.

if you want the resource relative from the root of the jar, then you should do getClass().getClassLoader().getResource()

Comment: I just tried it, and it still threw a null pointer exception. Could it be a problem that my resource folder is not a src folder?

Answer (score -1):

If you do not want to mess with the classpath and anyway, in any case, there's an overkill but 100% foolproof method that works that is based on the two following facts:

- it is always possible to find where the *.jar* that your class was (class)loaded from is located
- a *.jar* file is simply a zip file and Java has a default API allowing to read zip files.

It is overkill, but it "Just Works [TM]" (and due to various guarantees made by Java it cannot not work: you can *always* find the path to a .jar and *always* read from that *.jar*) and is convenient when you want to create a unique *.jar* that can be launched as is on Windows, OS X, Linux, etc.

We're using this overkill method on an app that is deployed on hundreds of different systems.